# What is valid syntax of and what are uses of @ at javascript?

Tags: javascript

Have viewed

```
@propertyOrIdentifier // ? What does this mean and do?
```

used within apparent plain objects or `class` assignment at Questions and Answers at stackoverflow.

What is the `@` symbol or character in `javascript`? What are valid uses?

Comment: citation needed?   The `@` symbol is used in e.g. Java for annotations, but not in JavaScript.  It's also not legal within an identifier.

Comment: @Alnitak At the first question viewed that is now deleted, both  `const a = {@b};` and `object.property .= @func;` were within body of Question. Second link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430943/es6-am-i-using-classes-mixins-correctly-in-javascript where `import { readonly } from 'my-decorators';class Person {
  @readonly
  person ( ) { return this.user; }
}` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a `decorator`.

https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators

[Medium - Exploring es7 decorators](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.fu11ljfe6)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have any special meaning in vanilla JS.

It's likely that wherever you are seeing it it is simply being used as a naming convention, similar to doing something like adding a preceding underscore for private variables `_example`